# Asp.Net site not showing in iFrame

Tags: c#, asp.net, iframe

I want to show an external site in an iframe. But I'm getting this error: "This content is not displayed in a frame".

```
 <div id="frameDiv" style="height: 900px;">
<iframe id="leftFrame" src="<%=leftLink%>" width="100%" height="100%" name="leftFrame"></iframe>
 </div>
```

I also use it as a meta tag:

```
<meta http-equiv="X-Frame-Options" content="SAMEORIGIN" />
```

Thanks.

Comment: There is an IE security setting, since you are loading external websites IE might stop this. 
Tools --> Internet Options --> security --> Internet Zone --> Custom Level --> Miscellaneous --> Launch programs and files in an iframe. with other browser Read the warning text - The publisher (google) does not permit hosting their site in an iframe or frame. Google does this by adding a http header, "X-FRAME-OPTIONS: DENY" which modern browsers will - and should - obey.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Comment: So I can not use an iframe in Chrome?

Comment: The site you are displaying in the iFrame, is it a site you own, or something out in public domain?

Comment: It is a site used internally but in another domain.

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
<iframe name="myIframe" id="myIframe" width="400px" height="400px" runat =server></iframe>
```

Expose this iframe in the master page's codebehind:

```
public HtmlControl iframe
{
get
{
return this.myIframe;
}
}
```

Add the MasterType directive for the content page to strongly typed Master Page.

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits=_Default" Title="Untitled Page" %>

<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPage.master" %>
```

In code behind

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
this.Master.iframe.Attributes.Add("src", "some.aspx");
}
```

Comment: Actually what error are you getting can paste the screen shot or some reference

Answer (score 0):

I've tried this solution and its useful in my problem:

- Open Internet Explorer and select "Tools > Internet options".

  Select the "Privacy " tab and select the "Advanced" button.

  An "Advanced Privacy Settings" window will open.

  Tick the "Override automatic cookie handling" button and "OK" back to
  Internet Explorer.

Now try your problem website.

Comment: Do not have a solution with code? Users need to work on all browsers without having to make this setting.